# Java Binary Translator

Tags: java

Im looking for some help on this binary translator problem. The question goes: In this exercise, you’ll write a binary to text translator!

As we’ve seen, every character can be represented by a string of 8 bits, or a byte. For example, the binary string 01000001<sub>2</sub> has the decimal value of 65<sub>10</sub>, which maps to the character ‘A’.

**So far I have this but the output is:** H 
                                      CÞ* 
                                      NÒ)MØ

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Scratchpad extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(binaryToText("0100100001001001"));
        System.out.println(binaryToText("010000110110111101100100011001010100100001010011"));
        System.out.println(binaryToText("010011100110100101100011011001010010000001001010011011110110001000100001"));
    }

    public String binaryToText(String binary)
    {
        String s2 = "";   
        char nextChar;

        for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length()-8; i += 9) //this is a little tricky.  we want [0, 7], [9, 16], etc (increment index by 9 if bytes are space-delimited)
        {
            nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(binary.substring(i, i+8), 2);
            s2 += nextChar;
        }
        return s2;
    }

    public int binaryToDecimal(String binaryString)
    {
        int decimal = 0;
            int base    = 2;
            for (int i = binaryString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (binaryString.charAt(i) == '1')
                    decimal += Math.pow(base,i);
            }
            return decimal;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. 010000012  is nine digits in length.  It does not match the problem description "... string of 8 bits ...".  1. Binary numbers can not contain the digit '2'.  3. 01000001 is the binary representation of the decimal number "65".  Which is significantly different from 6510.

Comment: "For example, the binary string 010000012 has the decimal value of 6510" - (a) you can't have a 2 in a binary string (b) 8 bits has a range fro 0 to 255, so the stated decimal value is incorrect

Comment: What OP is saying that 01000001_2 (base 2) is equal to 65_10 (base 10). What is the expected output?

Comment: *"(increment index by 9 if bytes are space-delimited)"*  - but they are not...

Comment: untested: `char[] ca = binary.toCharArray();
 String ascii = "";
 for(int i = 0, x = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
  if(i%8 == 0) {
   ascii += (char) x;
   x = 0;
  }
  x <<= 1;
  x += ca[i]-'0';
 }
 return ascii.substring(1);`

Comment: The mapping you are referring to is actually two mappings. A character set maps between a conceptual element of a writing system (CAPTIAL LATIN LETTER A or HAND WITH INDEX AND MIDDLE FINGERS CROSSED) and an integer (65, 129310) called a codepoint. There are many such character sets. Each codepoint is mapped using a storage scheme called an encoding. An encoded character is a sequence of 1 or more code units. A code unit is stored in one or more bytes. You're using Java's `char`, one UTF-16 code unit. Code comments can explain how that corresponds to the char set and encoding you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

For each string of bits, perform the following:

1. Create an array of 256 chars, the value of each element is the ASCII value of the index.  For example, the value of element 65 is the character 'A'.  This is the translationTable referenced below.
2. If the length of the string of bits is divisible by 8, continue.
3. If the string of bits contains only digits 0 and 1, continue.
4. Split the string of bits into smaller strings, each of which is exactly 8 digits in length.
5. For each 8-bit string, convert from binary to decimal.
6. Using the translationTable, convert from decimal to the desired ASCII character.
7. Accumulate the individual characters into a string (perhaps using a `StringBuilder`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Scratchpad extends ConsoleProgram
{

    public String binaryToText(String binary)
    {
        String s2 = "";   
        char nextChar;

        for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length()-8; i += 8) 
        {
            nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(binary.substring(i, i+8), 2);
            s2 += nextChar;
        }
        return s2;

    public int binaryToDecimal(String binaryString)
    {
        int numPlaces = binaryString.length();

        int currentExponent = numPlaces - 1;

        int decimalValue = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++)
        {

            int placeValue = (int) Math.pow(2, currentExponent);

            char currentDigit = binaryString.charAt(i);
            int digitValue = Character.getNumericValue(currentDigit);

            System.out.print(digitValue + " * (" + placeValue + ")");
            if(i != binaryString.length() - 1)
            {
                System.out.print(" + ");
            }

            decimalValue += digitValue * placeValue;

            currentExponent--;
        }

        System.out.println(" = " + decimalValue);

        return decimalValue;
    }
}
```